# IBM Watson Assistant: when I use @entity in intent training question, watson doesn't treat all entity value equally

Tags: nlp, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Let's imagine we are using a chatbot to facilitate the food ordering process in a restaurant.

We have the following settings in IBM watson.

Intent:
#orderfood with "can i order @food?" as sample question

Entity:
@food: burger, noodles, chicken

When I do the testing, the confidence level of "can I order burger" vs "can I order noodles" is different. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

To train a conversation service like IBM Watson Assistant you would typically have more than a handful of examples per intent or entity. If you have only defined few examples and just started, there is no training data. Chatbot services learn from user input and from the administrators correcting wrong processing (learning).

What confidence was higher? The first test or the second? Have you repeated the first test to see if the confidence increased...?